# Query doesn't select the different value

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello guys, I'm trying to get all id_user with different id of 1 and 5 but this query doesn't seem to work perfectly

This is the query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id_user) 
FROM post_comment 
WHERE (id_user <> 1 || id_user <> 5) AND id_post = 2
```

This query select the user with id 1 and 5 as well, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: you need AND not OR, if i understood the question correctly.

Comment: (1. id_user = 1) => 1 <> 1 || 1 <> 5 (false OR true = true) ---- 
(2. id_user = 5) => 5 <> 1 || 5 <> 5 (true OR false = true) => TRUE AND id_post = 2 - your query will return all distinct id_user where id_post = 2

Comment: I made this one for you http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbf3a/3

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(id_user) FROM post_comment WHERE id_user IN [1,5] AND id_post = 2;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id_user) 
FROM post_comment 
WHERE id_user <> 1 and id_user <> 5 AND id_post = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id_user)
FROM post_comment 
WHERE (id_user <> 1 AND id_user <> 5) AND id_post = 2
```

If you are using an OR operator in your query and you are also using a negation `not equal to` on the same field, in this case, every record would be selected. Every record would have only one value for this field, therefore `the condition is always true`.

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Comment: I have expanded and explained my answer, consider reviewing and appreciating :)